# Fill with variable number of ones

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

What's the best way to fill a variable with an unknown (at compile time) number of ones?  For example, let's say:

```
int n = 5;
int b = fillwithones(5);
```

now b contains 11111 (in binary).

I can't just hard code int b = 31 because n is not known ahead of time (in my application).

I could do something like this:

```
int b = pow(2, n) - 1
```

But using a pow seems very wasteful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use left shift and then subtract 1:

```
unsigned int b = (1U << n) - 1U;

// Broken down into steps
//  1           = 00000001b
//  1 << 5      = 00100000b
// (1 << 5) - 1 = 00011111b
```

The reason this works is *1 shifted left n times* is the same as *2<sup>n</sup>*, as each sole bit position represents a power of 2.

Comment: Best to use `unsigned` instead of `int` for this.

Comment: @TomZych: was in the process of that fix, you're quick sir ;)

Comment: I would choose `unsigned long long` `(-1ULL >> (sizeof (unsigned long long) - n)` but constant folding will yield the same result in any case.

Comment: @Alex `n` is not constant here, i guess; BTW multiply the `sizeof` by 8 (`CHAR_BIT`)

Answer (score 1):

A funny way to get the highest bits as 1 and the lowest bits as zero is using this nice trick:

```
#include <limits.h>

...

int b = INT_MIN >> n;
```

This works because shift left operation on a negative number will mantain the sign of the operation, and since INT_MIN is 10000....0000 shifting it by n to the left will give you n bits to 1, but on the other side.